# FFMPEG compand filter

Tags: ffmpeg

How to use compand filter for hard limit volume?
From documentation I get this argument: `compand=attacks=0:points=-80/-80|-12/-12|20/-12`
But when I use it, i get error:

```
ffmpeg -i vol_dump.ts -c:v copy -c:a aac -af "compand=attacks=0:points=-80/-80|-12/-12|20/-12" -f mpegs compand_dump.ts

[Parsed_compand_0 @ 0x7f8078f0b0c0] Missing attacks and/or decays and/or points.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f8078c193a0] Error initializing filter 'compand' with args 'attacks=0:points=-80/-80|-12/-12|20/-12'
Error opening filters!
```

Whats wrong? Thanks

Comment: You need to show the complete console output.

Answer (score 0):

Your ffmpeg version is probably too old.